# Prevent Zoom pop-out windows from being atop other apps?

Tags: macos, zoom-meeting

In Zoom app for Mac, if I pop out the chat and participant interfaces into windows separate from the main (meeting) app window, they will always cover other apps’ windows, even when focus is on other apps. Can I prevent this, and make them behave like any other app window?

Comment: Floating window behaviour is controlled by the app. If there's a pref for it you're good, if not, you're stuck.

Comment: Why would macOS even allow an app to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this question for over a year too, and it seems [many others have it too](https://www.reddit.com/r/Zoom/comments/iopsro/zoom_and_always_on_top/) ([here too](https://www.reddit.com/r/Zoom/comments/il0cbe/is_it_possible_to_stop_zoom_from_getting_stuck_on/)) and there's no known solution. Nothing in Zoom's settings will allow you to disabled it, and as far as I know you can't disable it on the actual system either.

Zoom is well known for doing things like this, you can't fully close Zoom without it being minimized to the system tray (then you have to manually go and close that) too.

It's just something we're all going to have to deal with, if you can, I'd switch to another meeting service if you really need to.